# Why I need to `ls -ld` in order to see a hidden directory which `ls -a` is not showing?

Tags: linux, ls

I have access to a compute cluster where most of the time I need to run `ls -ld /some_dir/my_dir` to be able to see and access this directory, otherwise it seems hidden and cannot be seen by `ls -a`. Anyone know why I need this ? it's the first time I come across such a directory.

*I think it's a mounted filesystem somehow cause it has a particular quota on storage.*

**Note** couldn't really figure it out from here https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html

Comment: Remember you can do `man <command>` to get all of the parameters. In this instance use `man ls`.

Comment: @RawleyFowler I know, and I did. This is why i referred to the link in my question.

Comment: What do you mean by "_it seems hidden and cannot be seen by `ls -a`_"? If you run `ls -a /some_dir/my_dir` you will see the contents of `my_dir` (probably `.` and `..`)

Comment: @roaima. I think he was running `ls -a` inside `/some_dir` and expecting to see a list, which he won't if the subdirs are automounted.

Comment: @roaima Getting info back from `ls -ld my_dir` depends on the permissions of the parent.  `ls -a my_dir` depends on the permissions of the directory. We really need to see the directory permissions.

Comment: @doneal24 (and @Bib) yes. It seems likely there's an automounter involved here somewhere but it's not at all clear

Comment: @roaima Yup, not clear, however, I reserve the right to read between the lines and come up with something completely and utterly wrong!

Comment: @Bib Is this a right or a mandatory action? Perhaps just business as usual?

Comment: @doneal24, given what crud I have posted before, BAU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is hidden, then it is probably being automounted. Once you try and access it or stat it in some way, the system will then mount it. The plain `ls -a` will not request a directory list from the cluster. Doing `ls -ld <somedir>` tells the automounter exactly which directory to mount. You may get a full list if you try `ls -a *`, but I doubt it.

Comment: Thanks ! in fact it is this auto-mounting that I was not familiar with !  I am now looking more into it

Answer (score 3):

In many programs, you can combine options; so `-ld` is equivalent to `-l -d`.

`-l` means "long-form list", i.e., more details than just the names of files.

`-d` means "if supplying a directory as argument, show me info on the directory, instead of on its content".

So, `ls -ld /some_dir/my_dir` will give you long-form information (among that, permissions) about the directory `/some_dir/my_dir` directory.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am pretty familiar with `ls` and its more common options. So I saw the definitions for `-d` but couldn't figure out why this directory is hidden till I run `ls -ld`. Maybe I didn't understand this part -> `long-form information (among that, permissions)`

Comment: just to add, as I edited my question. This particular directory is hidden until I run this `ls -ld` on it. `ls -a` will not show it

Comment: this seems woefully unrelated